# exclude div from parent style

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I'm trying to override the `.container` class in bootstrap. I'm using Drupal 7 and I have a css file for my theme which is working perfectly until I want to override the `.container`

my HTML

```
 <div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">
<div class="top-div" style=" width:100%;background-color: #676767; font-weight:bold; color:white;">
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

that PHP code will insert the class `.container`

I need to give the div with class `.top-div`a 100% size without any padding from the `.container` I've tried the child > selector and descendant selector and the :not(.top-div) methods nothing works. When I use the :not(.top-div) it applies changes on each and every page and element on the website AND the div which contains the `.top-div` which is really weird. Suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the CSS you have so far?

Comment: Nothing fancy really `.container > .top-div {padding-right: 0px !important; padding-left: 0px;}` like I said i've tried the > and descendant and :not()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bootstrap, the padding is applied on the container, not the inner divs. To override this on one element you need to give it negative horizontal margins.

Something like:

```
.container .top-div {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Where `10px` should be replaced by the padding on `.main-container`.

If this doesn't work right away you may need greater [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Bootstrap's built-in `.row` class [uses this method](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)

Comment: I did that and it was working but I thought it's not best practice?

Comment: In this case, when only applied to a single element, it's the least likely solution to cause maintainability issues down the line.

Comment: Well what I did was give the div more than 100% width and then do a `margin-left:-15px` because for some reason `margin-left` has an effect while `margin-right` has no effect what so ever

Comment: Hmm. Try setting `margin-right:-10px !important`. If that works, you know you just need a more specific selector.

Comment: Ahhh the `.row` does have negative margins true. I tried using an `!important` and it didn't help however I've swapped the order of my mark up and put the div inside the `.row` rather than the `.row` being inside it and it worked :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try:

```css
.main-container {
  position:relative;
}

.top-div {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">
    <div class="top-div" style=" width:100%;background-color: #676767; font-weight:bold; color:white;">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> text</div>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Because I need the padding effect on the rest of the page but no this particular div.

Comment: @MarwanAK Ok, I edited the answer as I didn't realise that this is what you were after.

Comment: of course this works. Why haven't I thought of that lol... I was looking for something simpler I guess. thanks. Will select as best answer in a bit, if no more convincing answers show up :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap css than you don't need to give any custom css

You try to just add `row` class in your `top-div` class

it's a in built in `bootstrap.css` So no need for any extra custom css.

```
.row {
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

**Example**

```
<div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">
<div class="top-div row" style=" width:100%;background-color: #676767; font-weight:bold; color:white;">
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">
<div class="top-div row" style=" width:100%;background-color: #676767; font-weight:bold; color:white;">
<div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> text</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Yup this is what @Alexander Gottlieb and I just concluded and it works without adding anything to the stylesheet since `.row` is a class to basically negate the `.container` padding he also provided a very helpful link. Thank you your answer is the closest after his